# Trying to call a method from another class

Tags: java, methods, call

I'm trying to set up an estate agent program but having an issue calling the method from another class. I need the program to check that the address entered by the user isn't already on the system and if it is let the user know. If not take the details for the new property.

I've got it so that I can enter a new property but stuck trying to call the method I need to check if it's already on the system

```
           case 3:
           System.out.println("Please enter the password:     ");
           String password = keyboard.nextLine();
           if (password.equals("ADMINISTRATOR"))
           {
              System.out.println("What's the address of the property you would like to add?");
              String street = keyboard.nextLine();
              **if (street.equals(myArray.findPropertyByStreet(myArray.getTown(street))))
              {
                 System.out.print("This property is already on the system");**
              } else
              {
                 keyboard.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("What is the house type?\n Detached\n Semi-detached\n Apartment\n 
                 Terrace");
                 String houseType = keyboard.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("What town is the property in?");
                 String town = keyboard.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("What is the properties postcode?");
                 String postcode = keyboard.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("What is the vendors name?");
                 String vendorName = keyboard.nextLine();
                 System.out.println("What is the vendor's contact number?");
                 String contactNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
                 if (contactNumber.length() == 11)
                 {
                    System.out.println("Contact Number stored");
                 } else
                 {
                    System.out.println("Invalid contact number");
                 }
                 System.out.println("Please enter the price of the property:    £");
                 int price = keyboard.nextInt();
                 Property propertySix = new Property(street, town, postcode, houseType, vendorName, 
                 contactNumber, price);
                 myArray.insert(propertySix);
              }
           } else
           {
              System.out.println("Incorrect password entered");
           }
```

This is the one I'm trying to call it into, and it's this line I'm having the issue with
`**if (street.equals(myArray.findPropertyByStreet(myArray.getTown(street)))) { System.out.print("This property is already on the system");**`

I'm trying to call the getTown method but maybe I'm completely wrong with that? These are the one's I have to call from:

```
         public Property(String myStreet, String myTown, String myPostcode, String myType,
               String myName, String myNumber, int myPrice) {
         street = myStreet;
         town = myTown;
         postcode = myPostcode;
         propertyType = myType;
         nameOfVendor = myName;
         vendorContactNumber = myNumber;
         price = myPrice;
         dateRegistered = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
         }//Property

         protected String getStreet() {
         return street;
         }//getStreet

         protected void setStreet(String newStreet) {
         street = newStreet;
         }//setStreet

         protected String getTown() {
         return town;
         }//getTown

         protected void setTown(String newTown) {
         town = newTown;
         }//setTown

         protected String getPostcode() {
         return postcode;
         }//getPostcode

         protected void setPostcode(String newPostcode) {
         postcode = newPostcode;
         }//setPostcode

         protected String getPropertyType() {
         return propertyType;
         }//getPropertyType

         protected void setPropertyType(String newPropertyType) {
         propertyType = newPropertyType;
         }//setPropertyType

         protected String getVendorName() {
         return nameOfVendor;
         }//getVendorName

         protected void setVendorName(String newVendorName) {
         nameOfVendor = newVendorName;
         }//setVendorName

         protected String getVendorPhoneNumber() {
         return vendorContactNumber;
         }//getVendorPhoneNumber

         protected void setVendorPhoneNumber(String newVendorPhoneNumber) {
         vendorContactNumber = newVendorPhoneNumber;
         }//setVendorPhoneNumber

         protected int getPrice() {
         return price;
         }//getPrice

         protected void setPrice(int newPrice) {
         price = newPrice;
         }//setPrice

         protected Date getDateRegistered() {
         return dateRegistered;
         }//getDateRegistered

        // Return the street, town and postcode
        protected String getFullAddress() {
        return street + ", " + town + " " + postcode;
        }//getFullName
```

Please can you point me in the right direction for this / explain what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Looks like getTown() is a method for Class Property. Property object should be reachable at that point and the right way to refer to that is:

```
property.getTown();
```

What is the type of myArray?
Why do you use getTown for method findPropertyByStreet?

Correct code should be like similar to that:

```
if (street.equals(myArray.findPropertyByStreet(property.getStreet())))
          {
             System.out.print("This property is already on the system");}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty hopeless with Java (but really want to learn) 'code' ArrayOfProperties myArray = new ArrayOfProperties(); or in another class I have 'private List<Property> properties;'          I thought getTown(street) would be a way to check the street against properties already on the system sorry.        I tried your recommendation but it's saying "Non-static method 'getStreet()' cannot be referenced from a static contect" Sorry I don't understand what that means